# How can I convert Google Maps plus codes to Lng & Lat coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, coordinates, open-location-code

I'm working on a project and I'm using some old google maps stuff. It requires longitude and latitude gps coordinates to get the location of a hospital for example.

I can't find a way to retrieve that info in this format 'lng,lat'

For example:   (34.417514, 8.7518123)

The only thing the new google maps has is plus codes (used by https://plus.codes/)  which they use as the location coordinates.

Can you guys help me find out a way to convert them to lng lat format or a way to retrieve the lng and lat from Google Maps website directly.

Or an alternative by saving my geolocation in a plus codes format in android studio (in a database of course) instead of using lat lng

https://www.up-00.com/i/00125/m4kadq6c7aeb.png

Comment: Where is your code and what have you tried?

Comment: I don't have the android app code right now becasue its on my other computer and I'm far away from home but I'm working on a web dashboard that retrives lat lng coordinates and put them in a google maps link like this : www . google .com / maps / place /@lng,lat yet it still very unaccurate and apparently plus codes are much easier and more easy to use to generate a working google maps postion link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert Plus Codes into `lat/lng` format via [Plus codes API](https://github.com/google/open-location-code/wiki/Plus-codes-API). If you have full (8-digits before "+" character, e.g. `8F6CCQCW+2F` for your location) Plus Code, you can locally (without any internet request) use [`OpenLocationCode.decode()`](https://github.com/google/open-location-code/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/openlocationcode/OpenLocationCode.java) method this way:

```
...
OpenLocationCode olc = new OpenLocationCode("8F6CCQCW+2F");
Log.d(TAG, "Lat = " + olc.decode().getCenterLatitude() + "  Lng = " + olc.decode().getCenterLongitude());
...
```

If you have short Plus Code (less than 8 digits before "+" character, e.g. `CCQCW+2F Gafsa` for your location, Gafsa is the area and it's used instead of using the full plus code) you can use `HttpURLConnection` with

```
`https://plus.codes/api?address=CCQCW%2B2F Gafsa&key=YOUR_GEOCODING_API_KEY`
```

(`%2B` is for the for `+` symbol)

(NB! you need [Geocoding API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) for geocode `Gafsa` part, which is the area, you need an area with a short plus code)
and get `location.lat` and `location.lng` tags from its JSON response:

```
{
  "plus_code": {
    "global_code": "8F6CCQJG+",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 34.432500000000005,
          "lng": 8.777500000000003
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 34.43000000000001,
          "lng": 8.775000000000006
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 34.431250000000006,
        "lng": 8.776250000000005
      }
    },
    "locality": {}
  },
  "status": "OK"
}
```

For "alternative" (saving my geolocation in a plus codes format) you can (fully local) use `encode()` method of [`OpenLocationCode`](https://github.com/google/open-location-code/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/openlocationcode/OpenLocationCode.java) class:

```
OpenLocationCode.encode(34.43125, 8.77625)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python implementation

```py
from openlocationcode import openlocationcode as olc 
olc.decode("8F6CCQCW+2F")
```

Output:

```
[34.42, 8.796125, 34.420125, 8.79625, 34.4200625, 8.7961875, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python solution:

```
>>> import openlocationcode
>>> openlocationcode.decode('8F6CCQCW+2F')
[34.42, 8.796125, 34.420125, 8.79625, 34.4200625, 8.7961875, 10]
```

Comment: sorry to say but its showing this error <br>
openlocationcode.decode('8F6CCQCW+2F')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'openlocationcode' has no attribute 'decode'